# Rubocop EnforcedColonStyle: table not applying to method call with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

We would like rubocop to align the arguments of a method call.

I tried using

```
Layout/AlignHash:
  EnforcedColonStyle: table
```

but it's not aligning the arguments:

```
# What it's doing
model.update_all(
  month: nil,
  year: nil,
  quarter: nil,
  on: nil,
)

# What we want it to do
model.update_all(
  month:   nil,
  year:    nil,
  quarter: nil,
  on:      nil,
)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: I've set as table (coping and paste how you say there) and it works for me. Maybe is something with your .rubocop.yml. And even reading rubocop documentation it should generate that. I've tried with ruby 2.6.3 and rubocop version 0.76.0

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are on ruby 2.3.7 which could be the cause.

Comment: I've tried with ruby 2.3.7 and rubocop 0.76.0 and it also works (I also like this format so I will add to my project ^^)

Comment: Would you be able to share your rubocop.yml with me?

Comment: Figured it out. I am inheriting a style-guide that has EnforcedLastArgumentHashStyle: ignore_implicit but I needed to change it to   EnforcedLastArgumentHashStyle: always_inspect

Comment: Note that Ruby 2.3 support is being dropped, so it's about time to upgrade. :-)